# Why the slashes in the URL of my Cloud Storage need to be encoded as %2F?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a file stored in the following folder of my Firebase Cloud Storage:

```
/logs/2021/03/2021-03-22.json
```

And I'm trying to access it through a download URL.

This does not work:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/o/logs/2021/03/2021-03-22.json?alt=media
```

I get this error when I try to open the file with the URL above:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

But the following URL works fine (when the slashes from the folder path are encoded as `%2F`), and I get the contents of the file as expected.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/o/logs%2F2021%2F03%2F2021-03-22.json?alt=media
```

Why is that? Will I always need to encode the slashes from the bucket's folder levels as `%2F` ?

Comment: not familiar with firebase storage, but is it possible that the part starting from "logs... is interpreted as an object/filename? Because if I wanted to encode a path with slashes in an URL I would do it exactly this way.

Comment: Slashes in a URL are normally interpreted as URL path compliment delimiters. For the server to do otherwise would be unusual, and perhaps even violate an RFC standard. Since instead you need your file to be interpreted as a single component, you have to *URL encode* it. This requirement is not peculiar to Firebase, and would apply to "unsafe" characters other than slashes. Whatever language you're working in can probably do URL encoding for you.

Comment: Both of these comments are the starts of great answers folks.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character `/` works as a path separator of individual elements of your URL, and `%2F` is converted into a `/`, then working as a separator in your URI.

Related to the question: *a % sign always indicates an encoded character, a URI may be made "safer" simply by encoding any characters considered unsafe, while leaving already encoded characters still encoded* [1].

Talking about Firebase, Google documentation says: *The part of the log name following /logs/ must be URL-encoded. This means that the forward-slash character, /, must be written as %2F* [2].

[1] https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html

[2] https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-management